# How to fix "Unknown label type: 'unknown'" when training a model by Fit Models

Tags: python, model, jupyter-notebook, training-data

I am a new user in python and I am trying to train a decision tree classifier, but I am getting an error each time. I tried in different methods but non of them works, I belief the problem is in the data type or representation which I change many times but I still have errors.

My problem is with the target which is string and I tried to use 
 MultiLabelBinarizer and  preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
but non of them work

```
# import arff data using panda
data = arff.loadarff('Run1/Tr.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])

# set the data and target
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
data = data.loc[:,'ATT1':'ATT576']
target = df['Class']

#split the data into training and testing
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)

# Create adaboost classifer object
abc = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=50, learning_rate=1)

# Train Adaboost Classifer ( I got the error here)
model = abc.fit(data_train,target_train)
```

### This is the error message

```
-
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2294376ac000> in <module>
      1 # Train Adaboost Classifer
----> 2 model = abc.fit(data_train,target_train)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    425 
    426         # Fit
--> 427         return super().fit(X, y, sample_weight)
    428 
    429     def _validate_estimator(self):
    enter code here

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    148                 X, y,
    149                 sample_weight,
--> 150                 random_state)
    151 
    152             # Early termination

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py in _boost(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight, random_state)
    484         """
    485         if self.algorithm == 'SAMME.R':
--> 486             return self._boost_real(iboost, X, y, sample_weight, random_state)
    487 
    488         else:  # elif self.algorithm == "SAMME":

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py in _boost_real(self, iboost, X, y, sample_weight, random_state)
    494         estimator = self._make_estimator(random_state=random_state)
    495 
--> 496         estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    497 
    498         y_predict_proba = estimator.predict_proba(X)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    814             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    815             check_input=check_input,
--> 816             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    817         return self
    818 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    152 
    153         if is_classification:
--> 154             check_classification_targets(y)
    155             y = np.copy(y)
    156 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    168                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 169         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    170 
    171 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'unknown'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because 'dtype' of the target is object check it by

```
    df.info()
```

if all the elements of the label column are same datatype then it is good but if some are str and some are int then it will show this error

To remove the error add one more line

```
    target = df['Class']
    target=target.astype(str)
    data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
```